# Ruby on Rails / Yellow Maps For Ruby Plugin woes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Okay I've read through the plugin comments and the docs as well and I have yet to come up with an answer as to how to do this. Here's my problem I want to use the :info_window_tabs and the :icon option, but I don't know what format to pass my information in. According to the documentation the following code should be correct. Here's my code:

```
        @mapper.overlay_init(GMarker.new([map.lat, map.lng],
        :title => map.name,
        :info_window_tabs => [
            {:tab => "HTML", :content => @marker_html}, 
            {:tab => "Attachments", :content => "stuff"}],
        :icon => {
                :image => "../images/icon.png"
                 }))
```

The readme and documentation can be viewed [here.](http://github.com/queso/ym4r-gm/tree/master)

And the relevant ruby file that I am trying to interact with, including the author's comments, can be viewed [here.](http://github.com/queso/ym4r-gm/blob/77821351d5f5b0c536e5fbdf89a4c853162ffa96/lib/gm_plugin/overlay.rb)

I have tried the #rubyonrails channel in IRC as well as emailing the author directly and reporting an issue at GitHub. It really is just a question of syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I finally got this figured out. Here's how you do it; :icon accepts a GIcon variable and :info_window_tabs accepts an array of GInfoWindowTabs. Here is how you would declare each with the plugin.

**Declare GIcon**

```
    @mapper.icon_global_init(GIcon.new(:image => "../images/civil.png",
       :icon_anchor => GPoint.new(0,0),   
       :shadow => "../images/shadow.png",
       :shadow_size => GSize.new(37,32),
       :info_window_anchor => GPoint.new(9,2)), "civil_icon")

    @civil_icon = Variable.new("civil_icon")
```

**Declare GInfoWindowTab**

```
    @tab1 = GInfoWindowTab.new('Tab 1 Label', 'HTML for inside of tab1')
    @tab2 = GInfoWindowTab.new('Tab 2 Label', 'HTML for inside of tab2')

    @window_tabs = [@tab1, @tab2]
```

Then in your GMarker declaration just do the following:

```
    @mapper.overlay_init(GMarker.new([map.lat, map.lng], 
            :title => map.name,
            :icon => @civil_icon,
            :max_width => 300,
            :info_window_tabs => @window_tabs))
```

And you're done.